# Rapahel js hiding elements on some area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

guys please see this link, http://www.logolenses.com/
i'm working on something very much similar to this,using raphael js instead of html5 canvas.
if we check the site, we can see that after adding an item on the left frame when we drag to the right side of the frame, it wont be displaying through the other customisable area.
i am not being able to achieve the same with raphael, tried toBack() and toFront() methods but no use.
can anyone help me?
thanks for any help

Comment: Need to see your example using raphaeljs

Comment: Also need much clearer explanation of what you want and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you seem to be saying is:

- You've got two areas acting as frames, next to each other.
- Shapes can be dragged into these frames, and sit behind the frames
- When you drag an object towards the middle, so it is behind both frames, it shows in both, because they are both part of the same paper object.
- You want the two frames to be independent of each other, so an image in one can't 'overspill' and show in the other.

So why don't you make each frame in its own independent paper object? If you want each to act as an independent area, why not make them into independent areas?

The areas defined as paper in Raphael crop on their defined boundaries by width and height, hiding anything outside the boundary. This clipping seems to be exactly what you want.

How you refactor to do that is up to you. One very easy way would be something like this:

```
function makeLens( id, width, height ){
   var paper = Raphael(id, width, height);
   var buttons = // find or place the buttons for this lens based on the id

   // the rest of your code

}
makeLens( 'left-lens', 500, 500 );
makeLens( 'right-lens', 500, 500 );
```

... with HTML / CSS like:

```
<style>
   .lens { width: 500px; height: 500px; float: left; }
</style>
<div id="left-lens" class="lens"> </div>
<div id="right-lens" class="lens"> </div>
```